# React Calculator: Handling Consecutive Operators after Multiplication/Division

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, calculator

I'm building a simple calculator application using React, and I'm having trouble handling consecutive operators, particularly after multiplication ('x') or division ('/') operations. For example, when the user inputs 5 + * 7, I want the result to be 35 (i.e., 5 * 7), and when the user inputs 5 * - 5, I want the result to be -25 (i.e., 5 * -5).
I've tried various approaches, including modifying my reducer function to account for these cases, but I'm still encountering issues. Here's the relevant part of my code,

```
export const ACTIONS = {
  ADD: 'add',
  CHOOSE: 'choose',
  CLEAR: 'clear',
  DELETE: 'delete',
  EQUALS: 'equals'
}

function reducer(state, { type, payload }) {
  switch(type) {
    case ACTIONS.ADD:
      if (state.overwrite) {
        return {
          ...state,
          current: payload.digit,
          overwrite: false
        }
      }
      if (payload.digit === "0" && state.current === "0") return state
      
      if (payload.digit === "." && state.current.includes(".")) return state

      if (payload.digit !== "0" && state.current === "0") {
        return {
          ...state,
          current: payload.digit,
        };
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        current: `${state.current || ""}${payload.digit}`
      }

    case ACTIONS.CLEAR:
      return {
        ...state,
        current: "0"
      }

    case ACTIONS.EQUALS:
      if (state.operation == null || state.current == null || state.previous == null)
        return state
      return {
        ...state,
        overwrite: true,
        previous: null,
        operation: null,
        current: evaluate(state)
      }

    case ACTIONS.CHOOSE:
      if (state.current == null && state.previous == null) {
        return state
      }

      /* Change operation */
      if (state.current == null) {
        return {
          ...state,
          operation: payload.operation
        }
      }

      if (state.operation === "x" || state.operation === "/") {
        if (payload.operation === "-") {
          return {
            ...state,
            previous: state.current + state.operation + payload.operation,
            current: null
          }
        }
      }

      if (state.previous == null) {
        return {
          ...state,
          operation: payload.operation,
          previous: state.current,
          current: null
        }
      }

      /*if (state.operation != null) {
        return {
          ...state,
          operation : payload.operation + state.operation,
          previous: state.current,
          current: null
        }
      }*/
      
      return {
        ...state,
        previous: evaluate(state),
        operation: payload.operation,
        current: null,
      }
    default: return state;
  }
}

function App() {
  const [{ current, previous, operation }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {});

  return (
    <div className="calculator">
      {/* Display section */}
      <div className="display">
        <div className="previous">{previous} {operation}</div>
        <div className="current">{current}</div>
      </div>
      
      {/* Buttons */}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.CLEAR })}>AC</button>
      <OperationButton operation="/" dispatch={dispatch} />
      <OperationButton operation="x" dispatch={dispatch} />
      {/* ... (other buttons) */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've attempted to address this issue by making modifications within the ACTIONS.CHOOSE case of my reducer function, aiming to account for consecutive operators after multiplication ('x') or division ('/'), i added this condition but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if (state.operation != null) {
        return {
          ...state,
          operation : payload.operation + state.operation,
          previous: state.current,
          current: null
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen something like (5 + * 7) working on a calculator. Usually, if you want to multiply something like negative numbers, you should input something like this: 5*(-3). But that is the case with negative numbers. I don't understand why you need to solve (5 + * 7). You can try your phone calculator to check the proper way it works.
When you input two consecutive mathematical operators (+-/*) without any numbers in between, the proper behavior is to replace the last operator with the new one. For example, if you have '567-5+' and you type '/', you should replace the last operator so the equation looks like this: '567-5/'.
If you want to work with negative values, you need to use '()' because that's the proper way to do it on a calculator and even on a school sheet. I recommend you start testing on a real calculator; it's a great way to become familiar with these concepts.
I hope it helps bro, if you still want to make 2 consecutive operator to work you can add conditions in between numbers and operators to add the '()' automatically but its not worth the effort.